I deposited 100$ and now i have only 40$
I i bought tokens of solana in price of 100$ ,after that i swapped it in to solana pudgy penguins. After few hours i swapped everything back to solana,because the price of penguin was still same. Now i have there only 40$.What happened? Where is rest of money. I transfered everytime everything. In transactions isn’t also anything.
